# How to hide your custom website.com website menu in their editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do something similar to https://mylapka.com/pem so that the text disappears and all the elements come back on the www.website.com editor. I am trying to create a div with a background image that covers all the elements and disappears when clicked on. It just wont cover the menu no matter what I try. Is there a way to do this. I am very new to coding and not very good at it so any help is greatly appreciated, trying to learn!

I put all the following code in a custom html box.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn').click(function(e){    
$('#fancy, #btn').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeIn('slow');
});
});

$('#btn-bk').click(function(e){    
    $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#fancy, #btn').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a id="btn">

<p style="background-image:url(http://i1158.photobucket.com/albums/p616/amattson21/
Untitled-1.png);width:1200px;height:800px;position:relative;z-index-1000;" 
align="center">
</p>

<p style="color:white;font-size:200px;margin-top:-250px;text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000000;"
align="center">
TEXT
</p>

</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out the codes I made. I created another html because I believe that this is the proper way to achieve the output you want.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj9eN/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
    <p>Your main website here.</p>
</div>
<div id="overlay">
    <p class="text">TEXT</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, #main, #overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
p, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#main {
    background:url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/old_map.png');
}
.text {
    color:white;
    font-size:200px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000000;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:10;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-150px -230px ;
}
#overlay {
    left:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    background:url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/old_map.png');
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#overlay').click(function (e) {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it works like a charm except for one thing and that is that when I exit the home page and come back it doesnt fade away when I click on it. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I don't get it. Is there also a sample of it?

Comment: Nevermind, I added
$(document).ready(function(){

});
and everything works perfect now